# How do you find the value of n in this example

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, systems-of-equations, trees, extremal-graph-theory

$$n^{n-2} = 16$$

I know $n = 4$ through trial and error but how do you find $n$ in a conventional manner?

I'm basically trying to solve how many nodes are in a tree that has $16$ spanning trees which through trial and error and using the right formulas, it equates to $5$.

Answer (score 4):

$n=3$ is not a solution. $n=4$ is solution.  If $n\ge 5$, then $n^{n-2} \ge n^{5-2}=n^3 \ge 5^3>16$, so, $n=4$ is the only solution.

Comment: "n=4 is the only solution" Not. See my answer.

Comment: n is a positive integer (lary said something about graphs)

Comment: I didn't see that stated in the original question. But I see the implication of his last sentence.

Comment: n = 4 which means that there are 4 vertices in the tree n+1 = amount of nodes there are. i was meant to say 5 nodes instead of 3 :)

Answer (score 4):

And I was thinking .2121 was the second solution.

[image]

Although 4 is fine, too.